# power pivot filter out zero-value in different context

Tags: excel, powerpivot

In the power pivot table below. I am trying to filter out the rows (subgroup) with no value. For example I would like to not display the value in the red frame in the image attached.

[image: table]

Because there are values in another group i.e. Sub group 11 & 14 are in group B they will still be displayed in group A even though their value in this filter context is 0.

Would there be any way to avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

to do this you need to drag qty2016 and qty2017 from field list to report filter.

So Qty 2016 and Qty 2017 will be taken in report filter and Value list.
 Once you have these variable in both the options  then deselect Blank from report filters for both the QTY's.

Regards